# how to show onsubmit validation message on client-side in javascript except alert pop up box?

Tags: javascript

I want to validate form inputs before submitting to the server side, so I am using onsubmit, but I want to show each error message separately by not using 'alert', is that possible? How to do it? Or onsubmit can only return message over alert?

**Update**
I already validated each of the input by using functions and there are error messages inside each function. But if I put these functions under "submit", when I click submit, no error message shows up.
here is my validation:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    myform.addEventListener("submit", function(){
    // validate all inputs
        validateName(); 
        validateEmail(); 
        validatePhone();
        validateAddress();
        validateCity();
        validatePost();
        validateProvince();
        validateProduct1();
        validateProduct2();
        validateProduct3();
        getAtLeastOne();
        validateDelivery();
        //validate input before submit
        if (validateName() && validateEmail() && validatePhone() && validateAddress() &&
        validateCity() && validatePost() && validateProvince() && validateProduct1() &&
        validateProduct2() && validateProduct3() && getAtLeastOne() && validateDelivery())
        {
             // at least one product input is not empty
            if (product1 !="" || product2 !=""||product3 !="")
           {
                return true;
           }
           else{
               erorMessage.innerHTML =`Input fields are required.`;
               return false;
           }
        }
    });
    

});
```

Comment: Typical approach a lot of applications take is to validate the field once the cursor's focus moves off of it. If there's an error, they just display the error text right above the text box. Not sure if I answered your question, though. I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, tbh.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code.

Comment: If you want separate error messages, display them in other elements without using `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting if there are issues. `return false` does nothing in an event handler attached using `addEventListener`.

```
myform.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    // validate all inputs
    validateName();
    validateEmail();
    validatePhone();
    validateAddress();
    validateCity();
    validatePost();
    validateProvince();
    validateProduct1();
    validateProduct2();
    validateProduct3();
    getAtLeastOne();
    validateDelivery();
    //validate input before submit
    if (validateName() && validateEmail() && validatePhone() && validateAddress() &&
        validateCity() && validatePost() && validateProvince() && validateProduct1() &&
        validateProduct2() && validateProduct3() && getAtLeastOne() && validateDelivery()) {
        // at least one product input is not empty
        if (product1 != "" || product2 != "" || product3 != "") {
            return true;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            erorMessage.innerHTML = `Input fields are required.`;
        }
    }
});
```